# Fetching data from server in chunck and adapt to listview dynamically

Tags: php, android, database, parsing

I have online database of about 10000 rows of data. I want to download this data from server to client android app . But downloading whole data at a time takes long duration, so i want to fetch only 5 rows first, then next 5 rows and so on. Also i do not know how to update my listView with this 2nd,3rd ...time fetched data dynamically .Can anyone help me??

Comment: it's depend on api supporting paging or not. if supporting then use  any lazy ListView loading opensource lib to load and refresh data on scroll

Answer (score 0):

You could use asynctask to request data into a while loop until all data is downloaded. The server has to accept interval petitions 
Pseudocode doInBackground:

```
int response = 0;
int start = 0;
end = 10;

while (reponse != -1){
    //conect to server and request data from start to end
    List<items> list = requestServer(start, end);

    if (list != null){
        publishProgress(list);
        responmse = -1;
    } else {
        start += 10;
        end += 10;
    }

}
```

Pseudocode onProgressUpdate:

```
// just update and refresh ListAdapter
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a php `getdata.php` file to serve data.

```
<?php

    $limit = 5;
    $offset = $_GET["page"] * $limit;

    //database query string
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable LIMIT " . $limit . " OFFSET " . $offset;

    //make db connection and print results as json
    //TODO

?>
```

Copy this EndLessListView to your project:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.AbsListView;

/**
 * Created by ozgur on 11/3/15 at 4:48 PM.
 */

public class EndlessListView extends android.widget.ListView implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {

    private boolean inEndOfList = false;
    private ListViewListener listViewListener;

    public ListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public ListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public ListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int scrollState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        int tot = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
        if(tot >= totalItemCount) {

           if(!inEndOfList) {
               inEndOfList = true;

               if(listViewListener != null)
                   listViewListener.onEndOfList();
           }
        } else
            inEndOfList = false;
    }


    private void init(Context context) {
        this.setOnScrollListener(this);
    }

    public void setListViewListener(ListViewListener listViewListener) {
        this.listViewListener = listViewListener;
    }

    public interface ListViewListener {
        void onEndOfList() ;
    }

}
```

Replace your ListView with above EndlessListView in activity's XML.

```
private EndlessListView listView;
private int currentPage = 0;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getData();

        listView = (EndlessListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setListViewListener(new ListViewListener() {

           @Override
           public void onEndOfList(){
               currentPage++;
               getData();
           }
        })
    }

private void getData() {
    //connect to getdata.php and send "currentPage" variable as "page" parameter 
    //add results to listView's data list
    //notifyDataSetChanged your adapter 
}
```